# regex to get name from the string in php

Tags: php, regex

I have no idea how to make a regex , that's why i am asking this question.I have one string like `chirag patel <chiragxxx@gmail.com>`

I have a regex to get email id from the string.

```
 preg_match("/\<(.*)\>/", $data['From'], $matches);
 $email = $matches[1];
```

How to get name from above string using regex?

my expected output is: `chirag patel`.

Comment: why negetive?? this is genuine question

Comment: You don't need regex for that: `$name = strtok($data['From'], '<');`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , i am already using a regex to get email id , so it's better for me to use it in one condition and get both name and email address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in php

```
$data['From'] = "chirag patel <chiragxxx@gmail.com>";
preg_match("/.*(?=\<(.*)\>)/", $data['From'], $matches);
print_r($matches); // 0 : name, 1 : email
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex

```
.*(?=\<(.*)\>)
```

check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/GvmJO5/1). here is the php code for the following

```
$re = '/.*(?=\<(.*)\>)/';
$str = 'chirag patel <chiragxxx@gmail.com>';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: How to implement it in php?

Comment: added to answer

Comment: Why are you using `preg_match_all`? `preg_match` is suffficient.

Comment: yes, edited, wasn't familiar with the php syntax used the code generator in regex101

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex to capture name and email address in 2 separate groups:

```
(\pL+[\pL\h.-]*?)\h*<([^>]+)>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uTFfOH/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(\pL+[\pL\h.-]*?)` # group #1 that match 1+ name consisting Unicode letters, dots, hyphens, spaces
- `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `<([^>]+)>`: group #2 to capture email address between `<` and `>` characters

**Code:**

```
preg_match('~(\pL+(?:[\pL\h-]*\pL)?)\h*<([^>]+)>~u', $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

You add a capturing group for the name.

```
preg_match("/(.*)\<(.*)\>/", $data['From'], $matches);
$name = $matches[1];
$email = $matches[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been answered but because it's in PHP, which supports named patterns, and because might look cool:

```
/(?<name>.*?) \<(?<email>.*?)\>/g
```

**name** and **email** will be keys in the **$matches** array.